# Dart-How to toggle swiper on and off dynamically when the button is pressed?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-swiper

I am using *flutter_swiper* to swipe images in my flutter application.I want to turn the swiper off when the button is pressed so, how can i do it in my existing code?

Here is my code:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  var eImage = [
    "img/eyes/1.png",
    "img/eyes/2.png",
    "img/eyes/3.png",
  ];

  double height = 200;
  int itemNo;
  double eh = 200;
  double ew = 200;
  double nh = 100;
  double nw = 300;
  double lh = 100;
  double lw = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("img/wal.jpg"),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(

                            children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment(0, -0.6),
                                child: Container(
                                  width: ew,
                                  height: eh,
                                  //color: Colors.purple,
                                  child: new SizedBox(
                                    child: Swiper(
                                      itemBuilder:
                                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                        return Image.asset(
                                          eImage[index],
                                        );
                                      },
                                      itemCount: eImage.length,
                                      itemWidth: 200,
                                      itemHeight: 200,
                                      control: new SwiperControl(),
                                      layout: SwiperLayout.DEFAULT,
                                      customLayoutOption: CustomLayoutOption(
                                          startIndex: 1, stateCount: 3) ///<--- here i am trying to start from 1st index
                                          .addRotate([
                                        0 / 180,
                                        0.0,
                                        0 / 180
                                      ]).addTranslate([
                                        Offset(-400.0, 0.0),
                                        Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                        Offset(370, -40.0),
                                      ]),
                                    ),
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 350,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ))));
                      }
  }
```

In this code i am able to swipe images from list but i want to disable it when a button(not given in code) is pressed so, how to toggle ON/OFF this swiper on button click dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Just Consume the touch before it reaches the Swiper, using absorb pointer

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        TheSwiperWidget(),
        AbsorbPointer(
          absorbing: _disabled,
        ),
      ],
    )
```

and in your button change the state

```
FlatButton(
 onPressed: (){
      setState(() {
        _disabled = !=_disabled;
      });
    }, child: Text('Disable'),
   )
```

Comment: but still the arrows will be visible.i want to remove arrows too so this solution won't work for me

Comment: look into the SwipeController, it might have ways to manually changing pages, use same _disabled variable to render or not to render the buttons